# Custom UITableViewCell doesn't show all contents

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My problem is that I have a custom cell that doesn't show all the contents showed in the storyboard.

cellForRowAt code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "menuCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MenuTableCell

    cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator;

    cell?.altriPiattiLabel.isHidden = true
    cell?.piatto3Label.isHidden = true
    cell?.sceltaMiglioreLabel.isHidden = true

    cell?.numeroMenuLabel.text = "Menù \(indexPath.row+1)"
    cell?.numeroPiattiLabel.text = "\(menus[indexPath.row].getPiatti().count) piatti"

    cell?.piatto1Label.text = "Piatto 1: \(menus[indexPath.row].getPiatti()[0].getDescrizione())"
    cell?.piatto2Label.text = "Piatto 2: \(menus[indexPath.row].getPiatti()[1].getDescrizione())"

    if (menus[indexPath.row].getPiatti().count >= 3) {
        cell?.piatto3Label.isHidden = false
        if(menus[indexPath.row].getPiatti().count > 3) {
            cell?.altriPiattiLabel.isHidden = false
        }
        print("heeeeere")
        cell?.piatto3Label.text = "Piatto 3: \(menus[indexPath.row].getPiatti()[2].getDescrizione())"
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell?.sceltaMiglioreLabel.isHidden = false
    }

    if(indexPath.row == menus.count-1) {
        cell?.sceltaMiglioreLabel.isHidden = false
        cell?.sceltaMiglioreLabel.text = "scelta peggiore"
        cell?.sceltaMiglioreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Custom cell code:

```
    import UIKit

class MenuTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var numeroMenuLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sceltaMiglioreLabel: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var piatto1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var piatto2Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var piatto3Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cliccaPerInfoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numeroPiattiLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var altriPiattiLabel: UILabel!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        sceltaMiglioreLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        sceltaMiglioreLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        altriPiattiLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        altriPiattiLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() { super.awakeFromNib() }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Storyboard settings:
[My cell settings in the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyidj.png)

"sceltaMiglioreLabel" and the disclosureIndicator are never showed up in the simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have few questions for you.
1. Did you check that all logic to hide/show your label is fine?
2. Since, the cells are reused, are you making sure, for correct condition, the label are set visible again?

Comment: I've tried to never hide the label, but the problem is the same.
I think the logic of the label is correct...but i don't understand why the disclosureindicator isn't showed.